# Jquery Dialog Box - to open when clicked a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have jquery datatable whose 1 column's each cell has hyperlink

```
<a href = "...../path/?id=1234" > 1234 </a>
<a href = "...../path/?id=1235" > 1235 </a>
<a href = "...../path/?id=1236" > 1236 </a>
```

they all are cells of a column in jquery datatable.

Now, I want to open this link in jquery dialog

Plus

I am new to javascript please tell me if i could 
have

```
<a href = "...../path/?id=1234" > 1234 </a>
```

id =1234 value in href tag stored in some variable as i have to further run some Django queries using the " id " value

Comment: You have missing double quotes after your `href` attributes.

Comment: @brewal - thanks i have made the correction

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to those links, and handle the `click` event.
For instance:

```
<a href = "...../path/?id=1234" class="dialog-link"> 1234 </a>
<a href = "...../path/?id=1235" class="dialog-link"> 1235 </a>
<a href = "...../path/?id=1236" class="dialog-link"> 1236 </a>
```

This is the jquery code (make sure it's after 'document(ready)`.)

```
$(".dialog-link").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault(); //Don't open the link as a default behaviour
//Call the dialog function here.
});
```